# Group by case-blind label

Tags: mysql

I have a query to retrieve some information from a table. One column in the table contains labels that users create. How do I group my results by label if some of the labels are the same but may have a slight difference in input, such as case:

```
Support
SUPPORT
support
```

Is there a way to compare labels irrelevant to case or is it by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only differences are case, you could pass it through a string function that sends it to lowercase:

```
GROUP BY LOWER(fieldname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change its character case.

```
Select..
From..
Where..
GROUP BY LOWER(columnName)
```

or

```
Select..
From..
Where..
GROUP BY UPPER(columnName)
```